# How to present PublishSubject as Observable in MVVM?

Tags: swift, mvvm, protocols, rx-swift

I have something like this:

```
protocol ViewModel: class {
    var eventWithInitialValue: Observable<Int> { get }
}

class ViewModelImpl: ViewModel {

    let eventWithInitialValue: BehaviorSubject<Int> = BehaviorSubject(value: 0)

    init() {
        eventWithInitialValue.onNext(1)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var viewModel: ViewModel?

    private let bag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        viewModel?
            .eventWithInitialValue
            .subscribe(onNext: {
                print($0)
            }).disposed(by: bag)
    }
}
```

I want to communicate with `viewModel` fields from `ViewController` as an `Observables`. But inside `viewModel` this fields should be a `[OneOf]Subject` types (for safety reasons).

Implementation above have a next compile time error -> `Type 'ViewModelImpl' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModel'`

Can anyone help with the implementation of these requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not with Rx, your error is related to your protocol

This will solve the current issue

```
protocol ViewModel: class {
    var eventWithInitialValue: BehaviorSubject<Int> { get }
}

class ViewModelImpl: ViewModel {

    var eventWithInitialValue: BehaviorSubject<Int> = BehaviorSubject(value: 0)

    init() {
        eventWithInitialValue.onNext(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but you did't fully understand my question

Comment: You viewModel is nil ... You have several issues with that code ... you didn't event initialize it weak var viewModel: ViewModel?

Comment: This all doesn't matter in this case. ViewModel will be provided from outside

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this `Type 'ViewModelImpl' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModel'` because you define the `eventWithInitialValue`'s type in your implementation as BehaviorSubject. 
What I can suggest is something like this

```
protocol ViewModel {
    var data: Observable<Int> { get}
}

class ViewModelImpl: ViewModel {
    private let dataSubject = BehaviorSubject(value: 1)
    var data: Observable<Int> {
        return dataSubject
    }
}
```